# Problems with fixing navbar to top of page

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, nav

For some reason when running the following code my navbar seems to be stuck in the middle of my screen. Based on other nav's i've made before it should be fixed to the top so i'm super confused. any help is appreciated!

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-nav align-items-center">
          <a class="navbar-brand bigbrand" href="{% url 'post_list' %}">My Tech blog</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.github.com">Github</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com">LinkedIn</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'post_new' %}">New Post</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'post_draft_list' %}">Drafts</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a>
            <a >Welcome: {{ user.username }}</a>
          {% else %}
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}" aria-label="Login">
              <span class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>


    {# The actual blog posts#}
          <div class="content container-fluid">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="blog_posts">
                      {% block content %}
                      {% endblock %}

                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
    {# SCRIPTS#}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/blog.js' %}"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

image of my output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

to

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

Comment: lol I swear I tried that first and it didn't work. regardless thanks so much for helping with such a simple silly mistake!

Comment: When debugging CSS related errors, the most common complicator is your own cached CSS file. My guess is that, the first time you tried it, the source CSS had not yet been reloaded/refreshed by the browser.